# How do I extend the root partition?

Tags: disk-management

I recently started using Elementary, and I would like to allocate some more of my disks free space to the root partition. I did some searching online, but did not find a solution that worked.

Here is how my disks are set up: [image]
How can I extend sda6 to fill up the entirety of the unallocated space?

Answer (score 0):

You should resize `/dev/sda3` (the extended partition) first and you root filesystem `/dev/sda6` after. You might need to do it from a boot cd / usb live system.